# Print Base64 string using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used the `html2pdf` npm package to send a base64 string of a pdf to my nodejs server. I then use Nodemailer to send that pdf to an email address setting nodeMailer property like:

```
let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Nodemailer contact" <foo@example.com>', // sender address
        to: 'abc@gmail.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Node contact request', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
        html: output, // html body
        attachments: [{
            filename: 'new.pdf',
            content: encodedpdf,
            encoding: 'base64'
          }]

    };
```

Now, I also want to print this PDF that is encoded Base 64 string to a windows printer using Nodejs. I have tried googling a way to do this but could not find anything useful.

Comment: Do I get it correctly you want to print on a server without a browser?

Comment: Yes. I want to print without a browser

Comment: The data will be sent to the server

Answer (score 0):

There is a [node-printer](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer) but I believe it does not support the latest Node. I used it once in the past and it kinda worked. It's supposed to work on Windows. In order to print a PDF, you need to [convert it to EMF format and then you can print it](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer/blob/master/examples/printPDFInWindows.js). Although there is a [node-podium](https://github.com/tojocky/node-pdfium) package which simplifies that, it's apparently not maintained anymore.

You might get more luck in installing some command line tools and calling them from Node.